# Npm link Angular 2 library when running Angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular

I am working on a component library for angular 2 and did an npm link with my Angular2 webpack application.  When I do not have the library linked it works but after I do an npm link and run the application I get the following error.  The providers in question are providers from this linked library as I call a function to get back an array and the use it like ...data.  The error happens on every provider apparently as I removed them one by one and each time the next one threw the error.  Again this error only happens when the library is linked.

Uncaught Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]

Comment: This problem seems to happen because there are two angular 2 versions available (because of the symlink the node_modules of the linked package shows up). Unfortunately I don't know how to solve it, it may be a Angular 2 specific problem. For now it seems that you have to unlink and npm install on every change in the library (or remove the node_modules folder from the library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Angular 2 checks if the provider is an instance of its base provider.

When you have a module that imports it's own angular2 instance the provider instance extends from the Module angular2 version/instance. But the main app uses its own angular2 version/instance, so it checks if the provider extends by the base provider from its own angular 2 instance.

So this is a Angular 2 bug. But its unclear when it will be fixed. until then you should follow my advice in the comment I made earlier and "npm unlink" and "npm install" when changes are done in the library (or remove the "node_modules" folder from the linked library)

Comment: Supposedly, this has been fixed:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2291